# I am revising analytic geometry and I came across the following question about angles between vectors.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, analytic-geometry

the resultant vector of two vectors is 50 units long, and forms an angle of 37 degrees with one of the component vectors A which is 10 units long, what angle does the other vector B form with A; I have no idea how to start solving it, I tried to set up systems involving the coordinates of the vectors, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using well-known trigonometry formulas?

Comment: Draw it. You get a triangle with two known sides and the angel between them. There are two solutions.